# How to pass value of textbox from anchor tag to controller method in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to pass value of textbox from anchor tag to controller method, basically i want to transfer it from javascript function to the controller method. I am not able to understand how to transfer the value to search and current page to controller. Below is a code snippet please help to solve it.. thanks..

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button1').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'Home/getUsersList',
                data: "{'searchString':'" + document.getElementById('searchString').value + "'}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#showData').html(response)
                    },
                    error: function () { alert("error"); }
                });
            });
        });
</script>

<body>
    @Html.TextBox("searchString")
</body>

<a class="@(p == ViewBag.CurrentPage ? "current" : "")" href="@Url.Action("getUsersList", "Home", new { page = p })">@p</a>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getUsersList(string searchString)
 {
         int page=1;
 }
```

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error on the request? Your controller action is expecting 2 parameters `int page, string searchString` and you are only sending `searchString`. This will most likely result in a 404 error.

Comment: one thing i notice.. your action of "ViewUser" is the method it's trying to invoke on the HomeController class...  why are you showing us "getUsersList"?

Comment: By mistake i have written ViewUser, I want to transfer only searchString, page will be local variable.But from the Anchor link tag. I have edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

At first I think your URL parameter is wrong, make it look like this so MVC will handle it using the routing table. Add the `dataType` parameter as well.

```
...
url: '@Url.Action("GetUserList", "Home")',
dataType: "json",
...
```

If it doesn't solve it, post more information about your problem (e.g. the request status (404?) or any .NET errors)

Comment: Thanks Marthijn.. I want to know how can i pass parameter directly from anchor link to controllers method.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of  @Html.TextBox("searchString")

```
<input type="text" id="searchString" value="@zyz" />
```

and simply do this

```
$('#searchString').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

in data section pass this with search string name.

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button1').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'Home/getUsersList',
                data: "{'searchString':'" + $('#searchString').val() + "'}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#showData').html(response)
                    },
                    error: function () { alert("error"); }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

i think this will work for you or firstly save the value of text box in other variable and then pass in data and then recieve in getUsersList controller method